# SQLiteDatabase, Id of inserted row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm a little bit confused if I insert a new row to a table by using SQLiteDatabase.insert() method and get a 1 as a result then the ID of that row is 1 and not a 0, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's the new row's id. Autogenerated [rowids start from 1](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 1):

The returned value is the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

See docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))